# redirect pip install message in running bash script

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script that contains a `pip install .` to update the source file (normally to replace the original one). And every time I try to run the bash file, it will output a lot of package installing message for me.

My question is how to avoid those messages while still having my own constructed `print` method output, for example, they might be located in some python file for outputting the result in the middle.

Comment: You can pass `-q` to `pip install` to make it more quiet (can be repeated several times).

Comment: You could also consider redirecting the pip install output to a log file (with `> log.txt` ) that you can analyse later for its content.